# JSON listing all identities in a set

Tags: python, json, set

I have recently started working with JSON. The code below shows a snippet of what I'm working with. In this example, I want to extract the set {1411, 1410, 2009, 3089}. Do JSON provide a method for this, or do I need to create it myself?

In case it is relevant, I'm working with Python.

```
{
  "1411": {
     "id": 1411,
     "plaintext": "Increases Attack Speed, and gives increasing power as you kill Jungle Monsters and Champions",
     "description": "<stats>+40% Attack Speed<br>+30 Magic Damage on Hit<\/stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Devouring Spirit:<\/unique> Takedowns on large monsters and Champions increase the magic damage of this item by +1. Takedowns on Rift Scuttlers and Rift Herald increase the magic damage of this item by +2. Takedowns on Dragon and Baron increase the magic damage of this item by +5. At 30 Stacks, your Devourer becomes Sated, granting extra on Hit effects.",
     "name": "Enchantment: Devourer",
     "group": "JungleItems"
  },
  "1410": {
     "id": 1410,
     "plaintext": "Grants Ability Power and periodically empowers your Spells",
     "description": "<stats>+60 Ability Power<br>+7% Movement Speed<\/stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Echo:<\/unique> Gain charges upon moving or casting. At 100 charges, the next damaging spell hit expends all charges to deal 60 (+10% of Ability Power) bonus magic damage to up to 4 targets on hit.<br><br>This effect deals 250% damage to Large Monsters. Hitting a Large Monster with this effect will restore 18% of your missing Mana.",
     "name": "Enchantment: Runic Echoes",
     "group": "JungleItems"
  },
  "2009": {
     "id": 2009,
     "description": "<consumable>Click to Consume:<\/consumable> Restores 80 Health and 50 Mana over 10 seconds.",
     "name": "Total Biscuit of Rejuvenation"
  },
  "3089": {
     "id": 3089,
     "plaintext": "Massively increases Ability Power",
     "description": "<stats>+120 Ability Power  <\/stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive:<\/unique> Increases Ability Power by 35%.",
     "name": "Rabadon's Deathcap"
  }
```

Comment: JSON is just a data format, not a library. The language you are using to process it is *always* relevant.

Comment: Can't you just read it into a dictionary and call keys()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others, JSON is a format and doesn't provide any API. Since you are using python, what you can do is

```
import json
my_data = json.loads(my_json)
print my_data.keys()
```

I assume your ids are same as keys. Also, you won't need to do `set` as keys are unique.

Answer (score 1):

No, JSON does not provide a method for that or any methods for anything at all.  JSON is just a format for representing data, nothing more.